# vscode F2 refactoring HTML "No result."

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, refactoring

vscode has an interesting refactoring feature when pressing F2 on a symbol

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring

[This seems to work fine for the file one.py in my current workspace, but does not work for the HTML file in the same workspace index.html (video linked)](https://vimeo.com/429743727)
(The end result in the HTML file is a notification toast with the text "No result.", I cannot get the notification toast to show further information)

Please let me know if you have info on why the F2-refactoring does not function in the HTML file.

Some previous workarounds for similar situations (found by googling) involve making sure that vscode has a folder open as a workspace, or being sure the subject file is in the current worksapce. This already true of both the HTML and python files in my case.

(The tutorial I am working through is from "[The Coding Train 'Working with Data and APIs in JavaScript 1.2'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfMkdvN-23o&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6YxDKpFzf_2D84p0cyk4T7X)" https://www.youtube.com/user/shiffman),

```
$ code --version
1.46.0

$ screenfetch -n
 OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
 Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-37-generic
 Uptime: 5d 9h 5m
 Shell: bash 5.0.16
```